# Without running python file and upon saving file, os.makedirs is creating a folder

Tags: python

In VS Code, I have a python file (test.py) which has below code and upon saving file every time, **os.makedirs** code of line is creating a new folder. How can I get rid of this ? or am I missing something

```
project_dir_path = os.getcwd()
reports_dir_path = os.path.join(project_dir_path+"/","Reports/")
current_date_report_dir_path = os.path.join(reports_dir_path,current_date)
current_datetime_report_dir_path = os.path.join(current_date_report_dir_path,current_datetime)
os.makedirs(current_datetime_report_dir_path)
```

Comment: Side note: I think you fail to understand the purpose of `os.path.join()`.

Comment: Either you really are running the file and you just think you're not, or the folder you're seeing has nothing to do with this code. We can't tell.

Comment: I have no doubt about purpose of os.path.join, but makedirs is creating directory. I am conscious about just saving test.py file not running because i have other part of code which is not executed

Comment: I mean adding path separators to the parameters. That is _literally_ what the function is made to do on its own.